# Can audio files be saved like photos and movies in iphone using objective C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

If our iphone application uses the inbuilt camera to click any picture, for saving the image into iPhone's photo library, we use *UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum* method. Likewise, to store any video recording into the iPhone, we use *UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum*

Is there any method to save any audio file into iPhone's Sounds library akin to both the methods mentioned above?

Comment: Which Sounds library are you referring to?

Comment: hello Ben, I am referring to Settings>General>Sounds in the iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to import audio into the iPod application from the phone.  iTunes (on the computer) is currently the only way.  You do have a few options to save the file though

1) Create a movie on your own with just the audio
2) save it to disk locally (in the documents directory) and provide a way to get it off the phone (such as [CocoaHTTPServer](http://code.google.com/p/cocoahttpserver/))
3) Email it.
4) Upload to a server

Comment: hello coneybeare, i think you misunderstood my query. It has nothing to do with iPod application in iPhone. I came across an Apple documentation stating that all the apps in iPhone are sandboxed, particularly iPod, it is read-only. I just want to know if there is any way to save an audio file(like ringtone) into Settings>General>Sounds when we do have methods to save photos and movie.

Comment: Apple currently provides no way of adding sounds to the sounds library without iTunes syncing up the ringtones.  If they add this into the API, I will be the first to use it as it could greatly improve my own apps

Comment: thanks coneybeare, lets hope Apple does include this functionality soon. Allow me to mention this please, your Ambiance is great but Causes is one notch above it. All the best!